# Rails ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exception not raised in after_create of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, callback

I have 3 very simple models

```
class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :receipt_items
end

class ReceiptItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_transaction
  belongs_to :receipt
private
  def create_transaction
    Transaction.new.save!
  end
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :transacted_at, :presence => true
end
```

So every time a new ReceiptItem is created, it triggers the after_create callback to create a new Transaction object using save!. But because Transaction requires that the column transacted_at to be present, Transaction.new.save! should raise an ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid every time, I assumed.

So then I created 3 tests:

```
test "creating an invalid transaction" do
    assert_raises ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do
        Transaction.new.save!
    end
end

test "creating invalid transaction in after_create" do
    assert_raises ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do
        ReceiptItem.new.save!
    end
end

test "creating invalid transaction in after_create of associated model" do
    assert_raises ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do
        r = Receipt.new
        i = r.receipt_items.new
        r.save!
    end
end
```

The first two tests passed as expected. The third test, however, failed because the exception was never raised. As a matter of fact, if I add the following lines after the 'r.save!' line:

```
r.reload
p r.inspect
p r.receipt_items.inspect
```

I could see that the Receipt and the ReceiptItem have been created successfully.

Furthermore, if I replaced

```
assert_raises ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do
```

with

```
assert_difference "Transaction.count", +1 do
```

I confirmed that the Receipt and the ReceiptItems were created but the Transaction wasn't. That means the creation of the Transaction failed, but was silently ignored, even though I used 'save!' as opposed to just 'save'.

Does anyone know if this is the intended behaviour, or is this actually a bug in Rails?

(Tried this in Rails 4.0.13 and 4.2.0)

#### Update

I've filed a bug report here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24301

Comment: could u update your question with an output of `p r.inspect` and `p r.receipt_items.inspect` aswell?

Comment: Sure, here they are:

"#<Receipt id: 980190963, created_at: \"2016-03-24 06:13:38\", updated_at: \"2016-03-24 06:13:38\">"

"#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ReceiptItem id: 980190964, receipt_id: 980190963, created_at: \"2016-03-24 06:13:38\", updated_at: \"2016-03-24 06:13:38\">]>"

Answer (score 1):

> The whole callback chain is wrapped in a transaction. If any before
>   callback method returns exactly false or raises an exception, the
>   execution chain gets halted and a ROLLBACK is issued; after callbacks
>   can only accomplish that by raising an exception.

So although [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution) states that raising an exception should at least roll the transaction back (and refuse to save your object), ActiveRecord seems not to discharge its duties.

It turns out that community has already met the similar issue (you should probably check out a [github discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17282)) with rolling back parent transaction during `after_save`. Some workarounds to this coming to my mind (and mentioned at github thread) include:

1. Raising something non-active-record-related, like `RuntimeError` during `after_save`:

   ```
    class ReceiptItem < ActiveRecord::Base
      def create_transaction         
        raise RuntimeError unless Transaction.new.save
        # NOTE: this error gonna propagate till you rescue it somewhere manually
      end
    end
   ```
2. Wrapping up your saving into an explicit transaction:

   ```
   class ReceiptItem < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :receipt
     # NOTE: we removed after_save callback here
     private

     def create_transaction
       Transaction.new.save!
     end
   end


   r = Receipt.new
   i = r.receipt_items.new
   Receipt.transaction do
    r.save!
    r.receipt_items.each &:create_transaction
    # NOTE: whole transaction gonna be rolled back
   end
   ```
3. Saving a transaction in a different manner then `after_save` callback. May be you could pre-check a `transaction` validness in validation section of `receipt_item`?

As of my point of view, this behaviour is not intended as it is not documented anywhere explicitly. Rails repo owners seem to not sight a significant attention to the corresponding issue, but it's still worth a try to remind them about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @twonegatives. #1 works but can only work as a short-term hack. #2 complicates my code because in some models I have quite a few callbacks and I'm doing this in various different places, so things could go out of hand pretty quickly. #3 breaks the modularity of my code so that's not something I want to do. So it seems like this is indeed a bug in Rails and I will file a bug report with them. Thank you once again.